# Fractional Polynomial interpreting interaction terms

Tags: regression, logistic, interaction, interpretation, fractional-polynomial

**Background:** I have developed a logistic regression model where I am trying to analyze the effect of socio-economic data of a family on their probability of receiving a home loan. I have used fractional polynomials to achieve linearity in my continuous covariates. One such variable is "disposable income" which comes significant in my main effects model. On testing for interactions, the transformed disposable income (Idisp__1) 'interacted' with banksavings (not transformed through fractional polynomials) and interactions came to be significant.

**Issue:** I am using a confidence interval graph as suggested by Hosmer and Lemeshow in [*Applied Logistic Regression*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470582472) to analyze the odds ratio of the interaction together with the two variables (i.e., dispincome$~\times~$banksavings, dispincome and banksavings). When I keep disposable income constant and increase my banksavings by one unit I get significant confidence intervals ( i.e., 1 does not show up on the different confidence interval lines) and I get intuitive results. However when I keep my banksavings constant next time and now decide to increase my disposable income by 1 my confidence interval lines start touching (or crossing) 1, thereby, implying insignificance.

**Question:** What does it mean when we have an interaction A$~\times~$B, and  keeping B constant we get significant confidence intervals, but keeping A constant we get insignificant B confidence intervals?

I am quite stumped and can't seem to find enough literature on the issue.